# Using Arduino for ISP with AVRDude?

Tags: arduino, isp

I have a custom board with an ISP header. It's my design, I can perfectly program it with AVR Dragon via ISP, with AVRDude.

I wanted to try programming it with an Arduino, and I only have one with CH340 chip.

It's a MEGA2560, I have:

- uploaded the ArduinoISP sketch onto the MEGA2560, then
- added a 10uF cap between GND and RESET pins of MEGA2560 (polarity OK)
- hooked "ICSP" header pins (1..6) to my custom board's ISP pins (1..6) (wires OK)

My custom board follow the standard ISP header pinout:

```
 1 MISO  VCC 2
 3 SCK  MOSI 4
 5 RST   GND 6
```

So now everything is hooked together from MEGA2560 ICSP to my ISP header.

AVRDude command I've tried:

```
>avrdude -V -pt13 -cstk500v1 -PCOM5 -b19200 -t

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
avrdude: device signature = 0xffffff (probably .xmega) (retrying)
avrdude: device signature = 0xffffff (probably .xmega) (retrying)
avrdude: device signature = 0xffffff (probably .xmega)
avrdude error: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
avrdude error: expected signature for ATtiny13 is 1E 90 07
        Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
        this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.


>avrdude -V -pt13 -cavrisp -PCOM5 -b19200 -t

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
avrdude: device signature = 0xffffff (probably .xmega) (retrying)
avrdude: device signature = 0xffffff (probably .xmega) (retrying)
avrdude: device signature = 0xffffff (probably .xmega)
avrdude error: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
avrdude error: expected signature for ATtiny13 is 1E 90 07
        Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
        this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.


>avrdude -V -pt13 -carduinoisp -PCOM5 -b19200 -t
avrdude error: invalid -P value: 'COM5'
        use -P usb:bus:device
avrdude error: unable to open programmer arduinoisp on port COM5

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Information lies everywhere, mostly outdated and incoherent, Google couldn't help.

What else might be worth to try?

Comment: Did you check if COM5 is correct on your Device Manager?

Comment: Yes. :) I got it working anyway, but not with the ISCP header on the MEGA but with GPIO 50,51,52,and 10.

Comment: That's good to hear. Cheers!

Comment: wire reset of the target to pin 10 of Mega